# Clear browser cache after new deployment React app

Tags: reactjs, caching

We are deploying our React application on the Google cloud platform using docker. When we deploy new codes, most of the new features work fine but not for all changes reflect the latest in the browser. Users have to open an incognito window or clear cache to see the new feature.

How can we make user receive the latest changes with out reloading or cleaning out the cache?